# Writing Large Xml Files in .Net (with Validation)

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, xsd

My application needs to write an Xml File, for which I have an `XmlSchema`. Because the file can be very large, I think it would be problematic to use the `XmlSerializer` together with the classes that were generated by xsd.exe.

I know I could use `XmlWriter` to write an arbitrary big Xml File, but that would mean that I have to manually write out every element and every attribte, which is prone to errors.

Is there a tool which can generate a "schema specific" `XmlWriter` class which helps me avoid errors?  Or, at least, one that throws anexception immediately when I write something illegal? Are there any other approaches I am not aware of?

-Mat

Comment: It's hard to say, because it depends on the number of items which the user selects, but I guess up to 500 megs.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to *write* it out without validation, and then have an extra step which *reads* it again using the schema (using `XmlReader` to read through, without ever actually remembering anything in memory). That step could be optional - initially always do it, then when you believe you've got any bugs out, you can eventually turn it off to improve performance. (Possibly leave the code in so you can turn it on again easily.)

Of course you shouldn't use this as your *only* check - unit tests should help to stop you from even getting that far :)